# Multiple executors for spark applcaition

Tags: apache-spark

Can one worker have multiple executors for the same Spark application in standalone and yarn mode? If no, then what is the reason for that (for both standalone and yarn mode).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can specify resources which Spark will use. For example, you can use these properties for configuration:

```
--num-executors 3   
--driver-memory 4g   
--executor-memory 2g   
--executor-cores 2
```

If your node has enough resources cluster assigns more than one executors to the same node.

You can read more information about Spark resources configuration [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/running-on-yarn.html).

Comment: i am not asking about the same node. i Know it can have more than one executors. but can it have multiple executors for the SAME SPARK APPLICATION?

Comment: Yes, workers hold many executors, for many applications. One application has executors on many workers.

Comment: But can one application has executors on the same worker?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter where executors for the applications are. They can be also on one worker.

Comment: can you please point me out where from you read this. Thank you

Comment: It's from Apache documentation: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html

Comment: Also, read this: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/apache-spark-resource-management-and-yarn-app-models/

Comment: I didn't find on any of the links where it's mentioned that one worker can have **multiple executors for the same application**.

Comment: "Executor - A process launched for an application on a worker node, that runs tasks and keeps data in memory or disk storage across them. Each application **has its own executors**"

"Each application gets its **own executor processes**, which stay up for the duration of the whole application and run tasks in multiple threads. "


Each worker can have more than one executor. It doesn't matter for Spark or YARN for which application is executor running. There aren't any causes why worker can have many executors but only for different applications.